# Correcting for offset

Tags: python, coordinate-system, r, geoprocessing

I have a shapefile with real-time kinematic (RTK) measurements as a line feature, which more or less corresponds with visible features in a raster layer (shaped as lines). These measurements however are not accurate enough, they show about a 1-3 m offset with the features in different raster layers. I'm looking for a way to automate the correction of the offset.

What I've come up with so far is converting the features in the raster image to vector, then measuring the average distance between the two vector files and use this as a measure for offset, then correct this.

The problems I have now are: how to properly measure the offset between two not similar vectors? The RTK is a line feature and the shapefile created from the raster images is one big polygon which looks like two lines, the initial line feature should be in the middle of those in the end. And, after successfully measuring the offset, how do I correct the offset?

Right now I'm using QGIS, but solutions using R or Python are also more then welcome. Let me know if anything in the question is unclear or incomplete!

Comment: What does RTK mean here? Also, any chance of an image of what's going on?

Comment: RTK = real-time kinematic GPS/GNSS data collection, but that should be better than 1-3 m. Maybe the base raster is wrong.

Comment: The RTK data are coordinates which are fed into a vehicle that will drove the given trajectory. On the rasters, which are pictures from drones, the tracks of the tires are visible. To analyze the surrounding area I need the RTK to be perfectly in the middle of the tracks. This is possible by georeferencing by hand, but I need to somehow automate this. I'll see if I can add a picture later today, right now I don't have acces.

Comment: For clarity, I found out that not the gps data on the ground is not accurate enough, but the GPS used on the drone acquiring the raster is causing the offset. The raster should shift, not the RTK.